# Hermes JMS stuck at splash screen when opened from SoapUI

Tags: soapui, hermes-jms

I am running **Hermes JMS 1.14** and **SoapUI 5.5.0**.

I haven't installed Hermes JMS while installing SoapUI so I am using Hermes separately.

With `hermes.bat` I am able to run Hermes JMS, but when I go in SoapUI `projects -> start Hermes JMS` then Hermes JMS is stuck at the splash screen (that Hermes logo) and nothing happens.

I have given the path to Hermes in `preferences -> tools` of SoapUI.

As no error or anything is coming in any of the logs of SoapUI or Hermes I am not sure which step I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to start the Hermes, it was some permission issue from SoapUI. Running SoapUI as administrator and launching Hermes fixed the problem.